# Is there short way to render CSS files by culture?

Tags: css, asp.net-core, razor, right-to-left, asp.net-core-3.0

Is there a way to tell .NET Core to render a `rtl.css` file by culture in one place for all pages, instead of wrapping every page that contain `rtl` files with an `if` condition?

```html
<environment include="Development">
    <link href="~/Styles/Site/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Styles/Site/layout-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</environment>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here is the CSS `:lang` selector. You don't need to load a different file in different scenarios, just add the RTL specific CSS in your main CSS like:

```
:lang(ar), :lang(he), :lang(fa) { /* Arabic, Hebrew, and Persian - add more as needed */
    /* RTL specific CSS */
}
```

You can also apply this more locally:

```
.myclass:lang(ar) {
    /* do something */
}
```

The `:lang` selector is supported in every single browser known to man, so compatibility is not an issue.